# How to trigger Form OnActivate event in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, events

I have to open many forms in an application and I'm using a TtoolButton and TActionlist as a menu bar.  I coded a procedure to create/show each form. I'm having difficult to trigger Form OnActivate event inside this procedure.
Each form is opened inside a Tpanel  which is located in the main form FormHome.
I appreciatte your help !

See my code in Delphi 10.2

```
procedure TFormHome.PR_OpenForm(Pform : TFormClass);
var
    vform : TForm;
begin    
           vform              := Pform.Create(Application);
           vform.Parent       := PanelCorpo;
           vform.Align        := alclient;
           vform.BorderIcons  := [biSystemMenu];
           vform.BorderStyle  := bsNone;
           vform.Show;
           vform.SetFocus;
           vform.OnActivate(??); // That is the issue, how to call this event ?      
end;
```

Thanks in advance !

**Adding complimentary information to explain why I need one single method to  create/open my forms **

This is the code I use to open each particular forms. I have one method to each form with exactly the same code. The only difference is the Form instance itself :

```
procedure TFormHome.OpenDiretorioExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
     if Not Assigned(FormDiretorio) then
     begin               
           FormDiretorio              := TFormDiretorio.Create(Self);
           FormDiretorio.Parent       := PanelCorpo;
           FormDiretorio.Align        := alclient;
           FormDiretorio.BorderIcons  := [biSystemMenu];
           FormDiretorio.BorderStyle  := bsNone;
           FormDiretorio.Show;
           FormDiretorio.SetFocus;
           FormDiretorio.OnActivate(Sender);  // In this way , OnActivate works fine
     end;
end;
```

**What I need/want :**

I need only one method to open all forms.  This  TFormHome.PR_OpenForm(Pform : TFormClass)  coded above is almost there, except by the OnActivate method that is not working !

Could you help me to fix that ?

## Thanks!

**Sample Code - Project with Old code and new code 
===> Main Form  "FormHome"**

```
... // This is the main Form  FormHOme which calls FormA, FormB and FormC
    // There is a TToolbar with 3 Toolbutton that uses a TActionlist 
    //  FormA and FormB are called by the old style method Action1Execute 
    //  and Action2Execute 
    // FormC is called by the new method PR_CreateOpenForm  , which
   //  presents the error
var
  FormHome: TFormHome;

implementation

uses
    UnitFormA,
    unitFormB,
    UnitFormC;
{$R *.dfm}


procedure TFormHome.Action1Execute(Sender: TObject);
// Action1 : OnExecute event,  called from ToolButton1
begin
     if Not Assigned(FormA) then
     begin
           FormA              := TFormA.Create(Self);
     end;
     FormA.Parent       := Panelhome;
     FormA.Align        := alclient;
     FormA.BorderIcons  := [biSystemMenu];
     FormA.BorderStyle  := bsNone;
     FormA.Show;
     FormA.SetFocus;
     FormA.OnActivate(Sender); // There is a code in OnActivate event in FormA
end;


procedure TFormHome.Action2Execute(Sender: TObject);
// Action2 : OnExecute event , called from ToolButton2
begin
     if Not Assigned(FormB) then
     begin
           FormB              := TFormB.Create(Self);
     end;
     FormB.Parent       := Panelhome;
     FormB.Align        := alclient;
     FormB.BorderIcons  := [biSystemMenu];
     FormB.BorderStyle  := bsNone;
     FormB.Show;
     FormB.SetFocus;
     FormB.OnActivate(Sender); // There is a code in OnActivate event in FormB
end ;


procedure TFormHome.Action3Execute(Sender: TObject);
// Action3 OnExecute event, called from ToolButton3
// This is the desired code to implment in all Action OnExecute event
begin
      PR_CreateOpenForm(TFormC);  // Fails in the  OnActivate event
end;


procedure TFormHome.PR_CreateOpenForm(PClassform : TFormClass);
// This routine should be used to create/open all forms
// 
var
    vform : TForm;
begin
      if Not Assigned(Tform(PClassform)) then
      begin
           vform              := Pclassform.Create(Application);
      end;
           vform.Parent       := PanelHome;
           vform.Align        := alclient;
           vform.BorderIcons  := [biSystemMenu];
           vform.BorderStyle  := bsNone;
           vform.Show;
           vform.SetFocus;
           vform.onActivate(self); // Does not work !! Tried with : vform.Onactivate(nil) - vform.Onactivate(Tform)
end;

end.
```

**FORMA - OnActivate event**

```
procedure TFormA.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
   begin
      Edit1.Text := 'content from OnActivate';
   end;
```

**FORMB - OnActivate event**

```
procedure TFormB.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin

     Edit1.Text := 'content from OnActivate';
end;
```

**FORMC - OnActivate event**

```
procedure TFormC.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin

        Edit1.Text := 'content from OnActivate';
end;
```

**Error when calls  PR_CreateOpenForm(TFormC)**

[image: Error when calls Action3]

**DEBUG** - running step by step reach this event handler error :

```
procedure TWinControl.MainWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  try
    try
      WindowProc(Message);
    finally
      FreeDeviceContexts;
      FreeMemoryContexts;
    end;
  except
    Application.HandleException(Self);
  end;
end;
```

Please let me know if I have to provide any other information/code in order to have your suggestions and valuable tips !

Thank you guys !

Comment: @Victoria, thanks for the quick reply !  I've tried  vform.onactivate(self) and it generates a runtime error "Access violation at address .." .

Comment: That `Self` was just an example. But no matter what you use there as sender, it smells. What is the aim behind?

Comment: @Victoria , as I said, I have many forms to create/open through  the menu and if I have to code the opening one by one , by providing the form name of each one, it will work, BUT it is not a good practice. That is why I need this method for passing only the Tformclass name .  I checked a similar post [Passing a class as a parameter of a procedure in Delphi XE] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495107/passing-a-class-as-a-parameter-of-a-procedure-in-delphi-xe)

Comment: @JRG I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that `vForm.OnActivate` is nil, that would explain the AV. Does the TForm class that `Pform` points to have an `OnActivate` handler assigned at design-time? This code isn't assigning one at runtime so it would have to come from the Form's DFM.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, thks.  Yes , the form which I pass as a parameter Pform  has an OnActivate event coded at design-time.

Comment: Extract the code into a separate method. Call that method from OnActivate. Call it any other time you need to execute it. But thus smells and until you explain why you want to do this we won't really be able to help you.

Comment: @David , thks. I added additional information in the post to explain my actual code and why I need this new method working in order to avoid code replication  for each form !   I hope I was clear and you guys can help me to sove this !! Thks.

Comment: @Tom.  I also did vform.OnActivate(nil), but the problem remains, i.e. , it generates an Access Violation  exactly in this point !

Comment: So you have a runtime error that you want help with but you won't supply a [mcve]. Surely you know to do that by now. You've spent enough time here to know that. [ask].

Comment: @DavidHeffernan , there you go a complete code with both methods , the one which works and the one which fails ! Pls, check post Additional 2.

Comment: Nope. Not a [mcve]. We can't see the `OnActivate` event handler that raises the exception.

Comment: Ooops this site was offline or in maintenance ... I couldn't conclude the post with additional code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165708/discussion-between-jrg-and-david-heffernan).

Comment: I'm pretty sure `Assigned(Tform(PClassform))` is not doing what you expect. You are hard-casting a `TClass` to a `TForm`, As you are using a hard cast, the compiler even let's that slip. But that does not make sense. You are trying to check if there already exists an instance of your form class, but that's no way to do that. I'm wondering as I get the access violation a lot earlier than on the line you indicate.

Comment: @nil, yes you're right.  The AV error is first occurig at the Assigned command, as well as at the vform.OnActivate(??) command.  Do you have any idea on how to check if the parameter PClassform passed  has alreade an instance ?  This check is important because if the Form exist I dont need to create another instance of it , just show it and run OnActivate event !!

Comment: See the answer of Tom. He is asking about that. Maybe a TDictionary<TFormClass,TForm>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

You asked in a comment

> The point is : given a parameter PClassForm of TformClass class, how to check if there is any instance of the such parameter created in the Application ? " ,

You can do this using a function like the `FormInstance` one below.  The `Screens` object of a VCL application has a `Forms` property, and you can iterate that, looking to see if one of the forms is a specified class, which is returned as the function's result (which it Nil otherwise).  Once you have found the instance, you could of course use a cast to call some specific method of it.

```
function FormInstance(AClass : TClass) :  TForm;
var
  i : Integer;
begin
  Result := Nil;
  for i := 0 to Screen.FormCount - 1 do begin
    if Screen.Forms[i].ClassType = AClass then begin
      Result := Screen.Forms[i];
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  F : TForm;
begin
  F := FormInstance(TForm2);
  if F <> Nil then
    Caption := 'Found'
  else
    Caption := 'Not found';
end;
```

**original answer**The way you've written your q seems to tangle up your actual technical q

> vform.OnActivate(??); // That is the issue, how to call this event ?

with a lot of issues which aren't directly related.  Rather that try to
invoke the `OnActivate` handler (If there is one), it may be better
to override the form's `Activate` procedure to do whatever special handling you want
and then leave it to the code in `TForm` to decide when to invoke the `OnActivate`.  This is less likely to wrong-foot other form behaviour (like in `TScreen`).

The code below shows how to do this.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
  protected
    procedure Activate; override;
  public
  end;

[...]
procedure TForm1.Activate;
begin
  inherited;
  Caption := Caption + ' called from TForm1.Activate';
end;

procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Caption := 'Activated';
end;
```

Of course, maybe you could just put the code you want to execute in OnActivate in the OnShow handler instead.

Comment: thks a lot !  however  I can't see how this code help me to trigger OnActivate ust after vform.show !! I really need OnActivate runs after vform.show .   Does it make sense to you ?  Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think whatever you want to do needs to happen in an onActivate event?  Why not just put it in the OnShow event?

Comment: that sounds good !  In fact the code I need to run just after show  the form can be placed in OnShow event !  I did that and it worked !  Great idea , thanks!  BUT I still have the issue to check if the form passed as parameter , the "PClassForm",  already exist in the Application.  The point is  : given a parameter PClassForm of TformClass class, how to check if there is any instance of the such parameter created in the Application ? " , i.e.  check if the form exist before to create it .  If it exists just show it (vform.show), otherwise create it !

Comment: Well, iterate the `Forms` property of the `Screen` object (see Forms.Pas).  If one of the forms is your target class, show it otherwise create an instance of it.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how to use the `Screen` object to find an instance of a specified form class.

Comment: @MartinA, that is it !   It worked as I needed ! SOLVED !  Thank you so much !!   I've  implemented it and also another method to using the same idea to check form instance existence  and CLOSE it when changing from one form to another !!    I appreciatted a lot your all valuable help !

Answer (score 0):

Try change the working OpenDiretorioExecute method to shown code below and tell me if you still get the error. Use vform.OnActivate(Self) inside PR_OpenForm. Please also show the OnActivate event handler for TFormDiretorio.

```
procedure TFormHome.OpenDiretorioExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FormDiretorio:=PR_OpenForm(TFormDiretorio) as TFormDiretorio;

(* if Not Assigned(FormDiretorio) then
     begin               
           FormDiretorio              := TFormDiretorio.Create(Self);
           FormDiretorio.Parent       := PanelCorpo;
           FormDiretorio.Align        := alclient;
           FormDiretorio.BorderIcons  := [biSystemMenu];
           FormDiretorio.BorderStyle  := bsNone;
           FormDiretorio.Show;
           FormDiretorio.SetFocus;
           FormDiretorio.OnActivate(Sender);  // In this way , OnActivate works fine
     end; *)
end;
```

Change PR_OpenForm to return vForm. I assume you need the variable FormDiretorio.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this piece of code:

```
if Not Assigned(TForm(PClassform)) then
begin
  vform := PClassform.Create(Application);
end;
```

If you look in the source for implementation of `Assigned()` you will see that it only checks wheter the passed in argument is nil or not. Thus, your code doesn't check for the existence of a form of type `PClassForm`, as you might think. It only checks whether the parameter `PClassForm` is nil or not.

In your case `Assigned()` returns `true`, the form is not created and subsequently `vform` contains whatever happens to be on the stack. That it only crashes at the line where you call OnActivate() is just a coincidence. You may have destroyed significant data (and probably have) by accessing the uninitialized `vform` variable.

To prevent errors like this to become fatal, you should initialize local pointer variables to `nil` if they might stay uninitialized. You probably also got a compiler warning for this but neglected it.

Already earlier I wanted to ask you where you plan to hold references to the forms that you create, so that you can access them, but I didn't, because it was not your question.

You need to decide on that and then use those references, both to check for existense and to access the forms.